# .htaccess redirect file.css to file.php

Tags: .htaccess

I have css file in a directory named (file.css) . How can I redirect a request to these (file.css) file with htaccess so that a php can process the requested css file. ex. /file.css -> /file.php  ?

only that 1 file (file.css)
other css file will continue as regular.

Comment: This is a bit confusing, someone requests `style.css` and you want a PHP script `script.php` to deliver the style sheet? And you want it for just *one* file `style.css`?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^file\.css$ file.php
```

This would redirect file.css to file.php. Remember to activate RewriteEngine. Though I am a little unsure what you actually want to achieve doing this.